# Ambiguous overload with different user cast operator for lvalue and rvalue cases

Tags: c++, type-conversion, rvalue

I try to compile this test code

```cpp
struct MyData { /*..*/ };

template < typename T >
struct Wrapper
{
    T m_value;

    operator T const & () const & { return m_value; }
    operator T && () && { return ::std::move(m_value); }
};

using MyWrapper = Wrapper< MyData >;

MyWrapper foo () { return {}; }

int main ()
{
    MyData first(foo());      // error: call of overloaded 'MyData(MyWrapper)' is ambiguous
    MyData second = foo();    // ok
    second = foo();           // error: ambiguous overload for 'operator='

    return 0;
}
```

I have defined two type conversion operators, one for lvalue and one for rvalue.
I expect that when using a temporary instance of a Wraper object, the conversion operator defined for rvalue will always be used. In the case of object constructing is true but in the case of object assigning is false. Why?

This code compiles with gcc 8.3 and works as expected. Compiler gcc 8.4 and above, clang and msvc do not compile this code.

I try to compile code and expect that when using a temporary instance of a Wraper object, the conversion operator defined for rvalue will always be used.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the full and complete build-log from the example you show. It should contain informational notes that could be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: Both operations are valid options with the same priority, so the compiler flags them as ambiguous.  This is one of the oddball situations that a const return value can be the tie-breaker, `MyWrapper const foo() { return {}; }` (although it is not idiomatic, so I recommend not using that style).

Comment: Adding to Eljay's comment, you could also remove the `const` from your implicit conversion operator, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/e76edx136), to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @JasonLiam It is perfectly valid, if weird. @OP Names such as `_Type` (starting with underscore followed by a capital letter) are reserved. Do avoid using them in real code (but no common compiler is going to complain).

Comment: Thanks @Timo. I found some hack for my issue [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5YMsa8dGr)

Answer (score 1):

`MyData data = foo();` looks for both constructors and conversion functions to perform the requested implicit conversion. The candidates are

```
MyData(MyData const&);  // implicitly declared
MyData(MyData&&);       // implicitly declared
operator MyData const & () const &;
operator MyData && () &&;
```

The constructor candidates are not viable because they require a user-defined conversion to initialize the first argument (which would result in an overall implicit conversion that uses two user-defined conversions).

To select one of the two conversion functions, the usual rules of overload resolution apply. The binding of the `Wrapper&&` implicit object parameter in the second case to `foo()` beats the binding of the `Wrapper const&` implicit object parameter to `foo() because` foo()` is an rvalue.

With assignment the story is a bit different. It *must* call an assignment operator, and the candidates are

```
operator=(MyData const&);  // implicitly declared
operator=(MyData&&);       // implicitly declared
```

So we have to find the implicit conversion sequence from `foo()` to `const MyData&`, and the implicit conversion sequence from `foo()` to `MyData&&`, and decide which implicit conversion sequence is better. This will determine the overload that's chosen. These implicit conversion sequences are:

- bind the implicit object parameter of `operator MyData const &` (of type `Wrapper const&`), then call `operator MyData const &`, then bind the `MyData const&` to the result (identity conversion)
- bind the implicit object parameter of `operator MyData &&` (of type `Wrapper &&`), then call `operator MyData &&`, then bind the `MyData&&` to the result (identity conversion)

The rules on ranking of implicit conversion sequences state that if two user-defined conversion sequences use different user-defined conversions (which is the case here, as one uses `operator MyData const &` while the other uses `operator MyData &&`) then neither one is considered better than the other. This makes the overload resolution ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I don't understand some things. Why is bind the implicit object parameter of `operator MyData () const &` (of type `Wrapper const&`)? We can't call a method on a temporary object that is specialized for an lvalue, why we can apply a custom conversion operator for temporary object specialized for lvalue?
How would you advise to efficiently implement the conversion operators for the wrapper class? Or should we always use explicit methods to access the wrapped value?

Comment: @ssoft const lvalue references can bind to rvalues